# eigenvalue of adjacency matrix of bipartite graph

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

let $m$ be a eigenvalue of adjacency matrix of bipartite graph and $(x,y)$ be  eigenvector of corresponding to $m$.
why can be $ (-x,y)$ eigenvector of adjacency matrix? how can we find $(-x,y)$ before we have eigenvalue of corresponding to $(-x,y)$?